# Linear combinations and linear dependence.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am a bit confused with this theorem:

The nonzero vectors $v_1, v_2,..., v_n$ in a vector space $V$ are linearly dependent if and only if one of the vectors $v_j, j >= 2$ is a linear combination of the preceding vectors $v_1, v_2,..., v_{j-1}$.

Does this mean that for example $v_4 = v_3 + v_2 + v_1$? Does it have to be a linear combination of all the preceding vectors? Or could it be just two of the preceding vectors ie. $v_4 = v_2 + v_1$? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if we can write one vector in our set as a linear combination of the others, then that initial vector is linearly dependent with the rest of the vectors.

Note that $v_{4} = 0v_{3} + v_{2} + v_{1}$ is a linear combination of $v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}$. So if a vector in the set doesn't play a role in the linear combination, set its coefficient to $0$.

Comment: But is it also possible that one of the vectors that form the linear combination is linearly independent?

Comment: Sure. $\{v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}\}$ could be linearly independent, but $v_{4} \in span\{v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}\}$. Note that $\{v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}\}$ don't have to be linearly independent, though.

Answer (score 2):

It means there exist constants $c_1,c_2,c_3$ such that $v_4=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3$. Any of those constants could be zero, that's fine.

Comment: Are the ones with the zero constants linearly independent?

Comment: Linearly independent *relative to what*? Whenever you talk about linear dependence/independence it is always relative to some set of vector(s).

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: Think about $(1,2,3,0)=1(1,0,0,0)+2(0,1,0,0)+3(0,0,1,0)+0(0,0,0,1)$. The vector on the left is linearly dependent on the set of 4 vectors on the right. But all 4 vectors on the right are linearly independent (to each other... meaning none of them can be written as a linear combination of the others).